# Уничтожение объекта по клику

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется несколько объектов на сцене, которые я хочу уничтожать по клику с помощью этой функции:

```
void OnMouseDown()
```

Как мне это сделать?

Comment: При касании чем? коллайдером, мышкой?

Comment: при касании мышкой

Answer (score 0):

```
private int scor = 0;
    void OnMouseDown(){
        scor = 1;
    }

    void OnMouseExit(){
        scor = 0;
    }
    void Update(){
        if(scor == 1){
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

реализовал таким образом, будет ли это являться приемлемым кодом или можно его улучшить.

Comment: void OnMouseDown(){
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

а так ?)

Comment: Одновременно смешно и грустно, Спасибо Огромное!

Answer (score 0):

```
void OnMouseDown(){
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```